# Knapsack Problem using Dynamic Programming: Mathematical Equation

Tags: notation, algorithms, computer-science, dynamic-programming

I am trying to understand the knapsack problem from the book:

[Algorithm Design](https://theswissbay.ch/pdf/Gentoomen%20Library/Algorithms/Algorithm%20Design%20-%20John%20Kleinberg%20-%20%C3%89va%20Tardos.pdf)

I can’t understand the following equation. This provides solution to knapsack problem in the context of Dynamic programming. So we have S small problems. But I can’t understand what is meant by max S summation of weight over subscript j.

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

[image: Algorithm Design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the maximum value of the sum of weights of items in $S$, considering all possible choices of $S$ that satisfy the two specified restrictions.  It can also be written as $$\max\left\{\sum_{j\in S} w_j: S\subseteq\{1,\dots,i\} \text{ and } \sum_{j\in S} w_j\le w\right\}.$$